# Drive runs at different speeds with different programs

Tags: python, windows

**I have a python script that checks the speed of the selected drive.**

It's 103 lines so I won't paste the whole thing, but the important parts are here:

```
# Write
start_time_w = time.time()
with open (location, "w") as f:
    try:
        f.write("0" * 1000 * 1000 * size) # We want size in MiB // size is int(64)
        f.close()
        finish_time_w = time.time()
    except Exception as e:
        # try removing the file if it was created
        try: f.close(), os.remove(location)
        except OSError: pass
        print(f"Something went wrong...\n{e}")
        input()
        return
time_taken = round(finish_time_w-start_time_w, 1)
print(f"Wrote {size}MiB in {time_taken} ({round(size/time_taken, 2)}MiB/s)")
```

and

```
# Read
start_time_r = time.time()
with open (location, "r") as f:
    try:
        f.read()
        f.close()
        finish_time_r = time.time()
    except Exception as e:
        # try removing the file
        try: f.close(), os.remove(location)
        except OSError: pass
        print(f"Something went wrong...\n{e}")
        input()
        return
time_taken = finish_time_r-start_time_r
print(f"Read {round(size, 1)}MiB in {time_taken}s ({round(size/time_taken, 2)}MiB/s)")
```

To test the accuracy of my program I ran a program called [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/) which shows the speed of a selected drive.

*All tests were ran without any background usage and writing/reading 64MiB*
I tested my removable USB drive `X:` (a patriot drive model 1633 PHMPH) and got these results with my program:

[image: My Software]

I tested the same drive with CrystalDiskMark and got these results

[image: CrystalDiskMark]

**Why are the wright results not matching with any of the 4 types of tests provided by CDM?**

**Why is my read speed plentifold higher than CDM?**

**How do I fix these issues?**

*(edit: I do realize that CDM has size in MiB and speed in MB/s, while my program has both in MiB, However the difference should not be this drastic, as 1 MB is 1.048576 MiB)*

Comment: You show 4 different CDM benchmarks. Which of those 4 are you trying to replicate? Are you sure you are replicating it accurately? If not, why would you expect the results to be the same?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I'm trying to replicate the 2nd test, a sequential read with only 1 queue

Comment: Have you tried to flush the file ? So that the OS tries its best to ensure the bits were written. But it does not explain the reading speed. Could it be caused by file caching done by the OS ?

Comment: @Lenormju I added `.flush()` to the writing function. and the write speeds are still off, and the read speed is still insane https://imgur.com/a/0V9N0lt

Comment: The soft is not open-source to my knowledge, so we can't easily know what it does that you don't (or the other way). You may be interested in using `strace` on Linux (or its equivalent on other OS) to know the truth. But to know what you are doing "wrong" we need to know what is the "right" way. I don't.

Comment: You say that you are "checking the speed of the selected drive", but I don't see any place in your code where you are working with the drive at all. Your code only does *filesystem* operations, not any kind of operation on the drive. So, you are not "checking the speed of the selected drive" at all, you are checking the speed of the operating system's file system implementation. Which better be pretty darn fast since that is its job!